# Why is notepad++ writing to my new document?

Tags: notepad++

I updated notepad++ and it started writing to the screen.

I quickly closed it not knowing what it was, but now I'm curious do I have a 'hacked' copy of notepad++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a tribute to Charlie hebdo, after they were attacked:

[image]

http://thedavidjohnson.com/2015/01/12/notepad-tribute-to-charlie-hebdo/

The 'Charlie Hebdo' edition is discussed here:

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.4-je-suis-charlie-edition.html